# Use H2 DB for testing in Spring Boot

Tags: sql, spring-boot, h2, spring-test

I have been working on a demo Spring Boot project that provides a REST API to perform CRUD operations on some entity classes. During the development of this REST API I have also created unit and integration tests to ensure the flows work as expected. During the integration testing phase I thought it would be better to create a separate DB for testing running on a test profile, rather then using the same development one. However, trying to set up the integration tests to use the test DB and perform the CRUD operations against the test DB turned out to be problematic for me.
To be more concrete, here are the properties files and the integration test class that caused issues:

--- src/main/resources/application.properties ---

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/employee-management-system
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:data-dev.sql
```

--- src/test/resources/application-test.properties ---

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:employee-management-system-test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

logging.level.sql=DEBUG
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:schema-test.sql
```

--- EmployeeRestControllerIntegrationTest.java ---

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@Sql(scripts = {"classpath:data-test.sql"})
class EmployeeRestControllerIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Spy
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    private EmployeeDto employeeDto1;
    private EmployeeDto employeeDto2;
    private List<EmployeeDto> employeeDtos;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        employeeDto1 = modelMapper.map(getMockedEmployee1(), EmployeeDto.class);
        employeeDto2 = modelMapper.map(getMockedEmployee2(), EmployeeDto.class);
        employeeDtos = modelMapper.map(getMockedEmployees(), new TypeToken<List<EmployeeDto>>() {}.getType());
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        employeeRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    void getAllEmployees_shouldReturnListOfEmployees() throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = template.getForEntity("/api/employees", String.class);
        assertNotNull(response);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
        assertThat(response.getHeaders().getContentType()).isEqualTo(APPLICATION_JSON);
        List<EmployeeDto> result = objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody(), new TypeReference<>() {});
        Collections.reverse(employeeDtos);
        assertThat(result).isEqualTo(employeeDtos);
    }

    @Test
    void getEmployeeById_withValidId_shouldReturnEmployeeWithGivenId() {
        ResponseEntity<EmployeeDto> response = template.getForEntity("/api/employees/1", EmployeeDto.class);
        assertNotNull(response);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
        assertThat(response.getHeaders().getContentType()).isEqualTo(APPLICATION_JSON);
        assertThat(response.getBody()).isEqualTo(employeeDto1);
    }

    @Test
    void getEmployeeById_withInvalidId_shouldThrowException() {
        Long id = 999L;
        ResponseEntity<String> response = template.getForEntity("/api/employees/999", String.class);
        assertNotNull(response);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        assertThat(response.getHeaders().getContentType()).isEqualTo(APPLICATION_JSON);
        assertThat(response.getBody()).isEqualTo("Resource not found: " + String.format(EMPLOYEE_NOT_FOUND, id));
    }

    @Test
    void saveEmployee_shouldAddEmployeeToList() {
        ResponseEntity<EmployeeDto> response = template.postForEntity("/api/employees", employeeDto1, EmployeeDto.class);
        assertNotNull(response);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.CREATED);
        assertThat(response.getHeaders().getContentType()).isEqualTo(APPLICATION_JSON);
        assertThat(response.getBody()).isEqualTo(employeeDto1);
    }

    @Test
    void updateEmployeeById_withValidId_shouldUpdateEmployeeWithGivenId() {
        Long id = 1L;
        EmployeeDto employeeDto = employeeDto2;
        employeeDto.setId(id);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON);
        ResponseEntity<EmployeeDto> response = template.exchange("/api/employees/1", HttpMethod.PUT, new HttpEntity<>(employeeDto2, headers), EmployeeDto.class);
        assertNotNull(response);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
        assertThat(response.getHeaders().getContentType()).isEqualTo(APPLICATION_JSON);
        assertThat(response.getBody()).isEqualTo(employeeDto);
    }

    @Test
    void updateEmployeeById_withInvalidId_shouldThrowException() {
        Long id = 999L;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = template.exchange("/api/employees/999", HttpMethod.PUT, new HttpEntity<>(employeeDto2, headers), String.class);
        assertNotNull(response);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        assertThat(response.getHeaders().getContentType()).isEqualTo(APPLICATION_JSON);
        assertThat(response.getBody()).isEqualTo("Resource not found: " + String.format(EMPLOYEE_NOT_FOUND, id));
    }

    @Test
    void deleteEmployeeById_withValidId_shouldRemoveEmployeeWithGivenIdFromList() {
        ResponseEntity<Void> response = template.exchange("/api/employees/1", HttpMethod.DELETE, new HttpEntity<>(null), Void.class);
        assertNotNull(response);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        ResponseEntity<Void> getResponse = template.exchange("/api/employees/1", HttpMethod.GET, null, Void.class);
        assertNotNull(getResponse);
        assertThat(getResponse.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        ResponseEntity<Void> getAllResponse = template.exchange("/api/employee", HttpMethod.GET, null, Void.class);
        assertNotNull(getAllResponse);
    }

    @Test
    void deleteEmployeeById_withInvalidId_shouldThrowException() {
        Long id = 999L;
        ResponseEntity<String> response = template.exchange("/api/employees/999", HttpMethod.DELETE, new HttpEntity<>(null), String.class);
        assertNotNull(response);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        assertThat(response.getHeaders().getContentType()).isEqualTo(APPLICATION_JSON);
        assertThat(response.getBody()).isEqualTo("Resource not found: " + String.format(EMPLOYEE_NOT_FOUND, id));
    }
}
```

Indeed when I run the tests:

- the application context is started
- the Tomcat container is initialized to run on a random port
- the Hikkari Datasource adds the connection to jdbc:h2:mem:employee-management-system-test

Afterwards, the application throws this exception with the following stack trace:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #8 of class path resource [data-test.sql]: INSERT INTO employees_experiences(employee_id, experience_id) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (5, 1), (5, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (7, 1), (7, 2), (8, 3), (8, 4), (9, 1), (9, 2), (10, 3), (10, 4), (11, 1), (11, 2), (12, 3), (12, 4), (13, 1), (13, 2), (14, 3), (14, 4), (15, 1), (15, 2), (16, 3), (16, 4), (17, 1), (17, 2), (18, 3), (18, 4), (19, 1), (19, 2), (20, 3), (20, 4)com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK9KRGPGEGMHONO5TCMUS7LBLJY: PUBLIC.EMPLOYEES_EXPERIENCES FOREIGN KEY(EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.EMPLOYEES(ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO employees_experiences(employee_id, experience_id) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (5, 1), (5, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (7, 1), (7, 2), (8, 3), (8, 4), (9, 1), (9, 2), (10, 3), (10, 4), (11, 1), (11, 2), (12, 3), (12, 4), (13, 1), (13, 2), (14, 3), (14, 4), (15, 1), (15, 2), (16, 3), (16, 4), (17, 1), (17, 2), (18, 3), (18, 4), (19, 1), (19, 2), (20, 3), (20, 4)
```

I understand the problem has to do with a foreign key constraint violation in the table employees_experiences (mapping table that was created because the Employee and Experience entities have a many-to-many relationship).
Even so, I don't know what should be done to solve this issue and make the tests pass. Any suggestions or recommendations on how to solve the issues or articles/videos that I should consider would be highly appreciated. Also, please tell me if I should provide more of the project code.

Comment: Spring Boot enables a conection pool that shares the same database instance for all connections. When you do that the second connections will execute the `schema-test.sql` multiple times, one for each connection. You probably need to do clean up work at the beginning of this script.

Comment: Ok, I get your point. I hoped the schema-test.sql would be executed only once when I have the "test" profile active, since the H2 test database instance is the one from the connetion pool that can be picked up when the "test" profile is active. 

Anyway, I found out that I can create a class that extends this so called TestExecutionListener to solve this issue. I overwrote the  beforeTestClass() where I got the DataSource bean from the context. Then, I created an instance of the ResourceDatabasePopulator to which I added the script schema-test.sql from the classpath and executed it.

Comment: Inside the EmployeeRestControllerIntegrationTest class I added at the class level the following annotation
@TestExecutionListeners(value = SchemaInitializerTestExecutionListener.class, mergeMode = TestExecutionListeners.MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS).

This should ensure that the schema-test.sql script is executed only once before all tests run. Unfortunately that's not the case. @SpringBootTest fails to load the application context and the tests are ignored.

Comment: I typically include a bunch of `DROP TABLE x IF EXISTS;` at the beginning of the SQL script, and problem solved. Not the most elegant solution but it works.

Comment: Ok, I added the DROP TABLE IF EXISTS statements in the schema-test.sql. Now, when I run the tests I get thrown:

org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [data-test3.sql]: INSERT INTO employees_experiences(employee_id, experience_id) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4)

and 

org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.project.ems.employee.EmployeeDto] and content type [application/json]

Comment: I made more changes. You can clone the project at https://github.com/GeorgeBacalu/employee-management-system/ and try to run the tests. Any suggestion on how to improve this demo project, not just the integration tests, is more than welcomed.

Comment: Is the `schema.sql` in the git repo?

Comment: The script to create the tables is in the src/test/resources. I called it schema-test.sql. Maybe I could just call it schema.sql and then I wouldn't need the properties: 
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:schema-test.sql
, since Spring knows automatically to look for schema.sql and execute it if it finds it.

Comment: I should have mentioned. All the changes are in the 01-architecture branch.